# how to run a job with specific 'branch' via api with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, git, jenkins

I managed to build the job 
with post request:

```
http://username:password@my-jenkins.com/job/JobName/build?token=token
```

[image]

Seems like I need to use 'buildWithParameters' and put value to the 'Branch Specifier' field, but I'm sure how to do it.

I will be grateful for any help.

Thanks in advance
Denis

Answer (score 0):

Use buildWithParameters :

> http://username:password@my-jenkins.com/job/JobName/buildWithParameters?token=token&branch=your-branch-name

Then 'your-branch-name' will be bound to $branch and will be available in the current job